# C++ "Pointer to object" and then back again

Tags: c++, pointers, object

Newbie question, possibly just confused. Thanks in advance:

Suppose I have an instance of an object (or perhaps a struct), obj1, of class class1. The following is standard pointer assignment:

```
class1 *p1 = &obj1;
```

And from now on, I can access the object's members by p1->member.

Question: How do I "go back", i.e., if I write:

```
class1 obj2 = *p_var;
```

one could think obj1 and obj2 were the same; but in reality, this last call just create a new object and called the copy constructor (I think).

Is there a way to make obj2 refer to the same instance as obj1, or this goes against the whole concept of "object"? Any references on this would also be useful.

Thank you!!

Comment: [the answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57483/2189130) are also worth looking at as they'll describe what situations where you'd use a pointer over a reference and vice-versa

Comment: Thank you! The second set of answers works wonderfully.

Comment: "one could think obj1 and obj2 were the same" - not if one has learned the basics from e.g. a good textbook. It might happen, though when trying to learn it from obscure YT videos or online "tutorials".

Comment: agreed: stackoverflow is much better.